# failed to get credential.state and getCredentialStateForUserID

Tags: objective-c, ios13, apple-sign-in

I can't get the credentialState from method getCredentialStateForUserID while other members got returned well.

I ran the app on iPhone 8, iOS 13 simulator.

```c
- (void)authorizationController:(ASAuthorizationController *)controller didCompleteWithAuthorization:(ASAuthorization *)authorization {

    if ([authorization.credential isKindOfClass:[ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential class]]) {
        ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential *credential = authorization.credential;

        NSString *state = credential.state;
        NSString *userID = credential.user;
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:userID forKey:currentAppleId];

        NSPersonNameComponents *fullName = credential.fullName;
        NSString *email = credential.email;
        NSString *authorizationCode = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:credential.authorizationCode encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        // refresh token

        NSString *identityToken = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:credential.identityToken encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        // access token

        ASUserDetectionStatus realUserStatus = credential.realUserStatus;

        NSLog(@"state: %@", state);
        NSLog(@"userID: %@", userID);
        NSLog(@"fullName: %@", fullName);
        NSLog(@"email: %@", email);
        NSLog(@"authorizationCode: %@", authorizationCode);
        NSLog(@"identityToken: %@", identityToken);
        NSLog(@"realUserStatus: %@", @(realUserStatus));

        ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider *appleIDProvider = [ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider new];

        if (userID) {
            NSString* __block errorMsg = nil;
            [appleIDProvider getCredentialStateForUserID:userID completion:^(ASAuthorizationAppleIDProviderCredentialState credentialState, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                switch (credentialState) {
                    case ASAuthorizationAppleIDProviderCredentialRevoked:
                        errorMsg = @"revoked";
                        break;
                    case ASAuthorizationAppleIDProviderCredentialAuthorized:
                        errorMsg = @"completed well";
                        break;
                    case ASAuthorizationAppleIDProviderCredentialNotFound:
                        errorMsg = @"credential not found";
                        break;
                }
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    NSLog(@"SignInWithApple state");
                    NSLog(@"%@", errorMsg);
                });
            }];
        }
    }
}
```

state: (null)

realUserStatus: 1 (ASUserDetectionStatusUnknown)

Why am I receiving this inappropriate values? 
any other values get returned well.

and I'm getting this error

2019-09-09 16:28:05.859082+0900 AppleSignin[57581:3353025] [core] Credential State request returned with error: Error Domain=AKAuthenticationError Code=-7001 "(null)"

Comment: Have you managed to sort out this problem please? If so can you share your solution?

Comment: just for quick check

1. add        

- (void)authorizationController:(ASAuthorizationController *)controller didCompleteWithAuthorization:(ASAuthorization *)authorization { 
  ...
  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:userID forKey:appleUserId];
}

2. call getCredentialStateForUserID in the method

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
   
}

Comment: Same happening to me, have you found a fix for this?

Comment: @ZoltanMagyar have you found any solution to this?

Comment: Did you manage to isolate the cause here? I'm running into the same issue and can't isolate the issue. It's happening on a device and even with a distribution profile through test flight.

Comment: There must be a way to test this on simulator. 
is this last step: getCredentialStateForUserID required ?

Comment: It just doesn't seem to be working in the simulator. All fine testing with a real device.

Answer (score 8):

Same happened to me and after some testing I discovered that it started to work when I used a device for testing. Also, on Simulator it would ALWAYS ask for Name/Email every time, even though the user had already granted that. This was also solved when I switched to a device: after the first time, the user won't get asked to grant permissions again, instead he will have to provide his PIN/Password to login.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Exact same code on a device and I got "authorized" instead of "notfound" -> absolute classic of the sim can't beat a real device

Comment: I get the same issue, but on device :(