# Sign in with Apple - ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider already signed in but notfound

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, apple-sign-in, sign-in-with-apple

recently I'm learning SiwA on

> https://fluffy.es/sign-in-with-apple-tutorial-ios/

I tried to learn step-by step, however, I met some wired problem when I used "ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider". I have saved the userID in local, but it returns notfound when using ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider. I also delete the Apple ID used before in

> Settings > Apple ID > Password & Security > Apps Using your Apple ID

But it stills return notfound when I re-login. Here is my code.

```
extension LoginViewController: ASAuthorizationControllerDelegate{
    func authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController, didCompleteWithError error: Error) {
        print("something bad", error)
    }
    func authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController, didCompleteWithAuthorization authorization: ASAuthorization) {
        if let appleIDCredential = authorization.credential as? ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential{
            UserDefaults.standard.set(appleIDCredential.user, forKey: appleAccount.userID)
        }
    }
}
```

```
if let userID = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: appleAccount.userID) {
            ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider().getCredentialState(forUserID: userID, completion: {
                credentialState, error in
                print(userID)
                switch(credentialState){
                case .authorized:
                    print("user remain logged in, proceed to another view")
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "LoginToUserSegue", sender: nil)
                case .revoked:
                    print("user logged in before but revoked")
                case .notFound:
                    print("user haven't log in before")
                default:
                    print("unknown state")
                }
            })
        }
```

It indeed print userID so userID is not nil. But seems it's not match with the Apple ID so it shows notfound? Here is the error

> [core] Credential State request returned with error: Error Domain=AKAuthenticationError Code=-7073 "(null)"

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by simulator, if we change to device, there is no such problem. See reference:

> [failed to get credential.state and getCredentialStateForUserID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57849628/failed-to-get-credential-state-and-getcredentialstateforuserid)

Comment: I have the same issue, but on device :(